# display month in french in wordpress/php?

Tags: php, date, date-time, timestamp

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
<?php <time datetime="<?php  echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i d-m-Y'))  ?>"
data-timezone="<?php  echo esc_attr($tz_param)  ?>"><?php echo esc_html(date_format($ts, 'F j  H:i')) ?></time> ?> // Line A
```

**Line A** returns the following date (which is in English):

```
July 10 21:30
```

`print_r($ts)` prints:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-07-10 21:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
July 10  21:30
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above at **Line A** above so that when the page is in french, it should return the **DATE IN FRENCH**.

This is what I have tried but it is still returning the date in Engllish.

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'){   /* If the page is in french */
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
?>
<time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i d-m-Y')) ?>"
   data-timezone="<?php echo esc_attr($tz_param) ?>"><?php echo strftime(esc_html(date_format($ts, 'F j  H:i'))) ?></time> // Line B
<?php } ?>
```

**Line B** still returns `english` even after using `strftime`.

Comment: ps `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` is the old method on getting the current language in WPML. use `$current_language = apply_filters('wpml_current_language', null);` instead.. more [here](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_current_language/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a custom function in wordpress called [date_i18n](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/#localization). so basically you do

```
echo date_i18n( 'H:i d-m-Y', $ts );
```

without the setLocale stuff..

find the function date_i18n and its parameters [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/).

you could even build in your translation all in there, without the language check before:

```
date_i18n( __( 'H:i d-m-Y', 'textdomain' ) );
```

(replace 'textdomain' with your theme textdomain..)

Comment: like this ? https://3v4l.org/bHP1o

Comment: @user5447339 yeah, that should work. doesn't it? check for my edit, you might not even need your language check before, since you can translate the dateformat within string-translation..

Comment: On using this echo date_i18n( 'H:i d-m-Y', $ts ); Its not displaying anything. Its blank.

Comment: what does your $ts say? is it a unix timestamp..?

Comment: `print_r($ts)` prints:

`DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-07-10 21:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
July 10  21:30`

Comment: I am not sure who downvoted the answer. It is definitely not me. I upvoted it now.

Comment: are you around ? Let me know.

Comment: should we use like this ? `echo date_i18n( 'H:i d-m-Y', $ts->getTimeStamp());`

Comment: @user5447339 yup, this is how you get a unix timestamp from a dateTime object.

Comment: `echo date_i18n( 'F j H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp());` display `juillet 18 01:30`. I am wondering what changes I need to make in the `echo statement` so that it displays 1st alphabet in caps like this `Juillet 18 01:30`

Comment: in php: `camel_case('your string')`, but i'd rather use css: `.your-class {text-transform: capitalize;}`. but if you ask me: the name of the month should start with a capital letter by itself?! no? not sure about french..

Comment: I did this  `echo ucfirst(date_i18n( 'F j H:i', $ts->getTimeStamp()));` and it worked.